# intellij cannot create class-file when creating test class with maven project

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I created a maven project, and my hierarchy is :

```
MyPro:
  .ideas
  src
    -main
       -java
          -mypackage
             -MyClass.java
    -test
       -java
          -mypackage
            - (PLACEHOLDER)
```

When I try to create MyClassTest.java at PLACEHOLDER i.e. in  test/java/mypackage, I got `unable to parse template class, cannot create class-file`.
But if I create TestMyClass.java file, it works. I wonder why is that?

Answer (score 8):

Do you have `MyClassTest.java` or something similar listed under:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Editor</kbd> → <kbd>File Types</kbd>→ <kbd>Text files</kbd> ?

If so, try removing that pattern and check if you can create the class.

---

I was able to reproduce this error in a standard maven project, after adding the following file type:

[image]

And then trying to create the `MyClassTest.java`:

[image]

And after removing the file type there were no problems creating the Test class.